# Digitally signed JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, code-signing

I've come across some (Microsoft generated) JavaScript files that look like this:

```
... SOME JAVASCRIPT CODE...

// SIG // Begin signature block
// SIG // MIIaVgYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIIaRzCCGkMCAQExCzAJBgUr
...
// SIG // 2Ee3yfXCMiZKY8Yv2h0=
// SIG // End signature block
```

My question is what is the purpose of this digital signature? Yes, I know it is signed with someone's public key and that it helps to identify the author of the file, and yes, I know that it also makes sure nobody has tampered with the file, but what do browsers do with it? How do they use it? What're the benefits of having it in your JavaScript file (besides making your files look much larger :)?

Comment: They're comment lines, so in theory nothing at all.

Comment: Maybe for some kind of future tech that validates the page to ensure it has not been modified by external forces (e.g. hacking)? Would need some additional protection, though, since the hacker could just replace or remove that block.

Comment: http://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/security/components/signed-scripts.html

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a signed script as described [**here**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176795.aspx) (WSH vbscript, but WSH can use jscript as well). I suppose is rather pointless in browser context though.

Comment: Yes, those were my thoughts exactly, but why would they put it there if there's no purpose for it?

Comment: Like Rick linked above, Netscape Navigator had the ability to check the digital signature on javascript, but it used jar files for that purpose instead of inline signing.  Would love to have the ability to only run digitally authenticated jQuery, node, or any other js.                      https://superuser.com/questions/1263840/how-can-i-force-firefox-to-execute-only-ev-digitally-signed-javascript

Answer (score 1):

The script looks like it may have been signed by Microsofts [SignTool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s9b9yaz(v=vs.110).aspx), or something similar.

I can think of two uses for this. One, as mentioned above, is to use it with the windows scripting host or some other non-browser engine that checks the signature before signing. The second is to verify the authenticity of the javascript files by checking the signatures at install time and/or periodically on the server side. This will enable administrators to verify that the scripts are not tampered with and that they, even after updates, come from a trusted supplier.

I guess this could come in handy for intrusion detection systems as well.

Answer (score 1):

Per @Kooilnc's [**link**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176795.aspx:)

> Digital signatures (introduced with WSH 5.6) provide a way for you to verify who authored a script, as well as a way to guarantee that a script has not been altered since it was written and signed. This does not necessarily mean that the script is "safe;" after all, virus writers can obtain digital signatures, too. However, digital signatures do provide two measures of protection:

Essentially, it's like the MD5 hash of a download; it lets you know that it's from the source you believe it is from and that it hasn't been modified since they provided it.